# "Spirit" as a drink and a soul

Tags: plural-forms

The word "spirit"  when it refers to   an alcoholic drink,  and a soul is countable.  But "spirit" used in medicine is uncountable. Right?

Comment: /Could you give an example of use of the "medical" spirit?

Comment: For example, "We use spirit to treat wounds."

Comment: No, that is not right.

Comment: We would often be more precise and say 'surgical spirit'. That's non-count. But surgical spirit, brandy, and methyl alcohol are all spirits (countable). Also a medicinal tincture (or 'spirit') is typically an extract of plant or animal material dissolved in ethanol (ethyl alcohol).

Answer (score 3):

Usually, alcoholic drinks are called "spirits", and aren't countable, as in definition 10 below. In a pharmaceutical sense, it can be either "spirit of X" or "spirits of X", as in definition 9 below, but it's still not countable.

When it comes to **types** of alcoholic beverages, then "spirits" may be countable, as pointed out in the comment.

When it refers to imaginary essences (souls) it is countable, as you noted.

[American Heritage Dictionary "spirit"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spirit)

9. often spirits (used with a sing. verb) An alcohol solution of an essential or volatile substance.
10. spirits An alcoholic beverage, especially distilled liquor.

Comment: I like different **spirits**. Gin, rum, whisky, brandy.

Comment: Interesting. Would you say you like four different spirits, or four different kinds of spirits?

Comment: I am happy saying four different spirits. "How to differentiate between a Spirit and a Liqueur? Traditional pure spirits are made from grains or other plants with the main six pure spirits being gin, vodka, brandy, tequila, rum and whisky, all of which have a high alcohol content of usually over 38% ABV.  "

Comment: You convinced me. I edited my answer.

Comment: I was using Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. Definition 11 an alcoholic drink. It says it's countable. That's why I thought I could use both a singular and a plural verb before "spirit" and "spirits" meaning alcohol. And #12 it refers to "spirit" used in medicine but it doesn't say "spirits" and says it's uncountable so only the singular verb should be used with it. Am I right? https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spirit_1?q=Spirit

Comment: I think that means that it's time for a drink.

Comment: @AntoniaA It's countable when you are talking about types of liquor, but not to individual servings of it. If you had three whiskey sours, you wouldn't say "I had three spirits". As to the medical/chemical sense, I would go with definition 9 from AHD- sometimes with an "s", but using a singular verb.

Comment: Thus, 1. "spirit" or "spirits"  countable  when we are talking about different drinks. "Spirit" is used with a singular verb but "spirits" with a plural verb. 2."Spirit" or "spirits" in medicine both "spirits" and "spirit" take a singular verb. In this sense "spirits" and "spirit" are uncountable.

Comment: @AntoniaA I think you've summarized it right.